# Displaying Lists in MVC Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, lambda, ienumerable

I am using the following:

Controller:

```
var mylist = db.Users.Where(m => m.Users.foo == vm.foo)
vm.UserList = myList.ToList();

return View(vm.UserList)
```

UserViewModel:

```
//edited for space
public IEnumerable<User> UserList {get; set;}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Model.User>
```

Must I use the actual User model in order to not get a model error

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Model.User>
```

Is there a way to use my `ViewModel` and still show the `UserList` or not use the `@model IEnumerable<>` and successfully show the list ?

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.UserViewModel>
```

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Your returning a `UserViewModel` to the view, so it needs to be `@model Project.Models.UserViewModel` (and you loop through it usng `@foreach(var user in Model.UserList) { ... }`

Comment: Try :  @model IList<Project.Models.UserViewModel>

Comment: Let me give this a try and I will let you know the results.  Thank you

Comment: @Dilip - I am getting the error 'UserViewModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can send `UserViewModel` to the view instead of sending list .

sample:

```
@model UserViewModel
<table>    
  @foreach (var user in Model.UserList.ToList())
  {
         <tr>
               <td>
                      @user.Name
                </td>  
           </tr>                 
  }
</table>
```

Comment: Let me give this a try and I will let you know the results.  Thank you

Comment: @BenCdev : does it for you?

Comment: This does not seem to be working.  'UserViewModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: userlist is defined in your view as IEnumerable<User>  in your view model.. convert UserList to  UserList.ToList()

Comment: Like this ?: public IEnumerable<User> UserList.ToList() {get; set;} in the view model...

Comment: like  Model.UserList.ToList() as shown in the answer.. Try the answer i posed .